# Routing to different services in Zuul over the same API

Tags: rest, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

In my MicroserviceZoo i have a Zuul gateway and 3 Microservices (service1,service2,service3) discovered by Eureka. Zuul shall represent them to the outside and act as api-gateway with loadbalancing (ribbon) and circuit-breaking(hystrix).

Now in the service routing i have a problem which may seem simple to fix, but i am stuck with this far too long.

What i want is that Zuul routes to service1, service2, service3 over the same API:

```
gateway:port/api/1/service1/public/time
```

should become

```
gateway:port/api/1/public/time
```

and

```
gateway:port/api/1/service2/public/stats
```

shall become

```
 gateway:port/api/1/public/stats
```

..such that /api/1/public/stats routes to microservice2 (which hosts the stats method) and /api/1/public/time routes to microservice1 (which hosts the time method)

This is my current Zuul-Config (in bootstrap.yml):

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api/1
  stripPrefix: false
  routes:
    time:
      path: /**/public/time
      serviceId: service1
    stats:
      path: /**/public/stats
      serviceId: service2
    stream:
      path: /**/public/stream
      serviceId: service3
  ignored-services: '*'
  strip-prefix: false
```

What am i missing?
How do you fine-grained route using Zuul and Eureka?

Comment: Unfortunately zuul from spring cloud can only strip prefixes. You want rewrite functionality which is only available in spring cloud gateway unless you write your own filter

Comment: thank you for the good hint @spencergibb would you recommend to migrate to spring cloud gateway or implement a filter myself? I think cloud gateway is more fit for the future probably, as it succeeds zuul..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

There is no way to do this easily in Netflix Zuul, as pointed out by Spring Cloud Gateway dev Spencer Gibb

> Unfortunately zuul from spring cloud can only strip prefixes. You want rewrite functionality which is only available in spring cloud gateway unless you write your own filter – spencergibb Jul 13 '19 at 20:37

The Solution is to switch to [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway), which should be easily possible for most deployments of Zuul.

there you can easily rewrite routes individually, e.g.:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
     - id: streamservice
          uri: lb://streamservice
          predicates:
            - Path=/stream/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/(?<streamservice>.*), /$\{streamservice}
     - id: otherservices
          uri: lb://otherservices
          predicates:
            - Path=/otherserviceendpoint
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/(?<otherservices>.*), /$\{otherservices}
```

To achieve the functionality asked in the question, which implied that some services dont get handled by the gateway at all, in cloud gateway define a locator rule
to only locate services (via Eureka el al discovery service ) that include "isongateway:true' as metadata in the gateways conf.yml:

```
  spring:
      cloud:
        gateway:
          discovery:
            locator:
              include-expression: metadata['isongateway']=='true'
              enabled: true
```

so in the services, that should be located & routed by gateway you add the tag to the conf.yml:

```
# this is so we can exclude all services that dont have this metadata in gateway
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          local:
            metadata:
              isongateway: true
```

...and now all other services are not routed by the gateway.